Is it possible to add a map boundary geojson file dataset to google maps API and then show a specific boundary on a query?
I have a geojson with London boroughs boundaries.
I want to create the following logic:

Add this as a dataset to Google maps API - I know how to do it

show a specific boundary like City of Westminster only when i search for this location and get Place ID: ChIJxwN8mDUFdkgRoGfsoi2uDgQ


Note that Place ID: ChIJxwN8mDUFdkgRoGfsoi2uDgQ is ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_3 which is not supported for Google boundaries out of the box.
This is my part of code where I use to show boundaries for LOCALITY and ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_2
useEffect(() => {
    if (!isMapInitialized.current || !map || !placeId) return;
    console.log('useEffect triggered. PlaceId:', placeId, 'Map:', map);

    async function findBoundary(map: google.maps.Map, placeId: string) {
        console.log('Finding boundary for Place ID:', placeId);
        const request = {
            placeId: placeId,
            fields: ['geometry'],
        };

        const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.getDetails(request, (place, status) => {
            if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK && place?.geometry?.viewport) {
                console.log('Boundary found, fitting map to viewport');
                map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
                styleBoundary(placeId, map);
                setIsBoundaryDisplayed(true);
            } else {
                console.log('No results or error occurred');
            }
        });
    }

    function styleBoundary(placeId: string, map: google.maps.Map) {
        console.log('Styling boundary for Place ID:', placeId);
        //@ts-ignore
        const localityLayer = map.getFeatureLayer('LOCALITY');
        //@ts-ignore
        const adminAreaLayer = map.getFeatureLayer('ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_2');
        
        const styleFill = {
            strokeColor: '#810FCB',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 3.0,
            fillColor: '#810FCB',
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
        };

        localityLayer.style = (params: any) => {
            if (params.feature.placeId === placeId) {
                return styleFill;
            }
        };

        adminAreaLayer.style = (params: any) => {
          if (params.feature.placeId === placeId) {
              return styleFill;
          }
      };
    }

    findBoundary(map, placeId);
}, [placeId, map]);

I thought maybe creating the data set and then I could access these dataset boundaries using             const datasetAreaLayer = map.getFeatureLayer('DATASET');
But it did not work
Thanks for the help

Which part isn't working?  Where does your code get to with all the console.logging?
